# How to remove 0 and/or Null from row SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Task Goal: Show id and last name of clients with exam charges totaling at least $300.00 and no more than $900.00.

I tried filtering it out using HAVING but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN SUM(ED.ex_fee) >=300 and SUM(ED.ex_fee) < 900 THEN CL.cl_id END,'') AS cl_id,
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN SUM(ED.ex_fee) >=300 and SUM(ED.ex_fee) < 900 THEN CL.cl_name_last END,'') AS cl_name_last
FROM vt_clients as CL
INNER JOIN vt_animals AS AN ON AN.cl_id = CL.cl_id
INNER JOIN vt_exam_headers AS EH ON EH.an_id = AN.an_id
INNER JOIN vt_exam_details AS ED ON ED.ex_id = EH.ex_id
GROUP BY CL.cl_id, cl_name_last
HAVING CL.cl_id <> 0 and CL.cl_name_last <> ''
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT CL.cl_id, cl_name_last
FROM vt_clients as CL
INNER JOIN vt_animals AS AN ON AN.cl_id = CL.cl_id
INNER JOIN vt_exam_headers AS EH ON EH.an_id = AN.an_id
INNER JOIN vt_exam_details AS ED ON ED.ex_id = EH.ex_id
GROUP BY CL.cl_id, cl_name_last
HAVING SUM(ED.ex_fee) >=300 and SUM(ED.ex_fee) < 900
```